# Boxes and lines in Ncurses through SSH

Tags: ncurses

I am devoloping an small app. that is based in Ncurses that should be executed remotely via ssh on a server. That applications shows, among other things, some boxes (made with *box* or *wborder*). It also has a command line and some menus. It starts by showing nice, but from time to time, when a new character is entered in the command line or the pointer in a menu moves the whole screen starts flickering and showing weird symbols.

I tried to change the characters that are used to draw the lines in the borders, simply redefining the constants such as ACS_VLINE and ACS_HLINE, etc. Then, there's no problem, though I'd prefer to use the default characters, since they're prettier.

I googled and I found out this is caused by something related with the locale settings ncurses works with, the one that the ssh connection works with and the one of the terminal emulator (gnome-terminal in my case). I tried to fix that, but with not much luck. I presume this is a common issue. Anyone one has been able to solve a problem like that?

Comment: Have you tried with different terminals? xterm for instance

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is with UTF-8 encoding? If that's the case, try with setting the environment variable NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS to 1:

```
export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1
```

in `bash`-like shell or in `csh`-like shell:

```
setenv NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS 1
```

Thanks to [grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity) for their [answer](https://superuser.com/a/278337/169569) on SuperUser.